# Error- Can't Specify the external Sharing Model for Account in Force.com IDE

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I am getting this error when i am deploying my metadata components using Force.com IDE.

> Can't Specify the external Sharing Model for Account

So how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi, could you please specify more details? More verbose error description and your items that you are trying to deploy?

Comment: I am trying to deploy Account,Lead,Contact,Opportunity,Syndicator(Custom Object)  email templates , Reports and Dashboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that the sharing model org wide defaults are the same in your source and target orgs. By default it's set to private sharing model. The developer may have set it to a public sharing model and you'd need to do that through Setup UI in the new org you want to deploy to.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_owd_external_setting.htm